# Using Criterion 'OR' to narrow resultset

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, liferay, criteria

I'm having trouble understanding how to implement the following query using Criterion:

```
SELECT * FROM FooTable WHERE bar = '1' OR bar = '2;
```

This is what I have currently:

```
public List<FooItem> getFooItems(List<Long> bars) throws SystemException {

    DynamicQuery query = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(FooItem.class, PortletClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());

    if (Validator.isNotNull(bars)) {

        List<Criterion> barCriteria = new ArrayList<Criterion>();

        for (long bar: bars) {
            query.add((RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("bar", bar)));
        }

        if (!barCriteria.isEmpty()) {
            for (Criterion criteria : barCriteria) {
                query.add(criteria);
            }
        }
    }

    List<FooItem> result = FooItemLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(query);

    return result;
}
```

However, my query looks like the following at runtime:

```
SELECT * FROM FooTable WHERE bar = '1' AND bar  = '2';
```

How can I turn these `AND`'s into `OR`'s statement?

Note: *`bar` is not the primary key on the table.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Restrictions.disjuntion()`, try something like this

```
if (!barCriteria.isEmpty()) {
    Disjunction or = Restrictions.disjunction();
    for (Criterion criteria : barCriteria) {
        or.add(criteria);
    }
    query.add(or);
}
```